# Finding the right regex

Tags: regex

I am working on web-project with several languages: each HTML text inside a tag must be wrapped inside a `<?php echo _("..."); ?>` so :

`<div>My text</div>` transforms into `<div><?php echo _("My text"); ?></div>`

The fact is I want to track the huge amount of these occurrences of text in order to transform it into texts wrapped by a `'php echo'`?. Does it exist a regex to track these occurrences?

Comment: Use a HTML parser, then manipulate the text inside all you want.

Comment: Are you generating PHP code using another language?

Comment: Obligitory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Regular expressions are inadequate for parsing HTML.  Any solution that is given to you that is based on regexes will lead to sorrow in the future.

Comment: @danseery: I wish people would stop posting that link.  It's only funny to those who already understand the problems of parsing HTML with regexes.  To the people who need instruction, it makes no sense.

Comment: What do you mean by html parser ?

Comment: @AndyLester not too long ago I asked a similar question.  I did my research and found this wiki funny and informative.  Most likely, OP has not seen it and i'm just sharing the love

Comment: In fact, the html is parsed by the software that detects php echo occurrences and then translate the text

Comment: Info: I want to use the regex with the grep function